# Is there a simple way to use a different Spring version?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to use latest Spring 4.1.x snapshot in my Spring Boot project.

Is there a simple way to override the version of all Spring dependencies, or should I include all required Spring dependencies with it's desired version manually?

Reason is I want experiment with Spring 4.1 @JsonView annotation in REST services.

Comment: try introducing maven in your project and let it handle dependencies. It will be a one time effort but once done upgrading to versions will just be a one liner change

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using Maven with `spring-boot-starter-parent` as the parent, you can override the `spring.version` property in your pom to change the version of Spring that you're using:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.version>
</properties>
```

If you're using Gradle, you can achieve the same effect by using a resolution strategy to override the version of everything with the `org.springframework` group id:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency {
            if (it.requested.group == 'org.springframework') {
                it.useVersion '4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: note that details.useVersion should be it.details.useVersion

Comment: Thanks, Marcel. Correction made.

Comment: Andy, with latest Gradle version, I think you have to write `eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->` instead of `eachDependency {` to make it works (as proposed by Marcel)

Comment: @SébastienDeleuze Thanks. `it` is a `DependencyResolveDetails` so `it.details` was wrong with `it` being sufficient. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: For Maven, looks like the property is now `<spring-framework.version>` rather than spring.version (as of Spring Boot 2.1.0, at least).

Answer (score 2):

I once again needed this and previous block doesn't work anymore, causing already dependencies to be failed.

Anyway this works:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == "org.springframework") {
                details.useVersion "4.1.0.RC1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using Spring Boot, I'm guessing that you must be using either Maven or Gradle, but you don't say which. For Maven, you have a couple of things you might be able to do.

First, you could have a go at just forcing the Spring version in your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.version>
</properties>
```

That ought to override the property which is defined in the `spring-boot-dependencies` project.

For more fine-grained control, use dependency management:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```