# Custom transaction managent in spring boot application with @EnableAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm implementing custom transaction management for a cache memory (simple `HashMap` at this time) in a spring boot application. The application already uses `JpaTransactionManager` configured by some magic behind `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. And this is problem, because application tries to load two `PlatformTransactionManager`s and throws:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: cacheTransactionManager,transactionManager.
```

Transaction manager class:

```
@Component
public class KpiCacheTransactionManager extends AbstractPlatformTransactionManager{
...
}
```

My transaction manager is loaded by this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class CacheTransactionConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "cacheTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager cacheTransactionManager() {
        return new CacheTransactionManager();
    }     
}
```

Main application is runned using this configuration:

```
@Configuration("MyApplication")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan("com.foo.bar")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.foo.bar")
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@ComponentScan("com.foo.bar")
@ImportResource({...})
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
}
```

I've found some possible solutions (`@Primary` annotation, manager names,... ), but I don't know how to set this on existing configuration with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, how to override the default configuration for `JpaTransactionManager` with my own.

Env: Java 8, Spring Boot 1.2.1, Spring 4.1.4, Spring data JPA 1.7.2, Hibernate 4.3.7, Apache Tomcat 8.0.15

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a bug in Spring Framework 4.1.4. We are releasing 4.1.5 soon but in the meantime please downgrade to 4.1.3.

See [SPR-12577](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12577)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I set spring version for spring boot? I tried to set <spring.version>  to in <properties> in my pom.xml as described here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402073/is-there-a-simple-way-to-use-a-different-spring-version], but the application is still running with version 4.1.4 (from log file "Running with Spring Boot v1.2.1.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.4.RELEASE")

Comment: that only works if you're using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent. You are probably integrating boot yourself using the `spring-boot-dependencies` in scope `import`? Just add `spring-framework-bom` with scope `import` as well *before* the boot one.

Comment: Yes with this setting I'm able to run my app with spring 4.1.3, but it's throwing same exception. However I've added explicit creation of JpaTransactionManager bean to CacheTransactionConfiguration with @Primary and the exception disappears. Now I have problem with transactionmanager itself - it's working from JUnit tests (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner), but ignored from application (cacheTransactionManager methods are not called), but this is another question for separate thread.